# OpenGL error #1281 when attaching shader to program

Tags: c++, c, opengl, shader, glew

Im getting OpenGL error #1281 when attaching a compiled shader to my program.
Here is the vertex shader code:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;

void main(){
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

Here is the fragment shader code:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 color;

void main(){
  color = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Here is the method that creates the shader (program):

```
Shader::Shader(std::string vsfilename, std::string fsfilename)
  :program(glCreateProgram()) {
  const char* vscode = fileToString(vsfilename.c_str());
  const char* fscode = fileToString(fsfilename.c_str());

  unsigned int vs, fs;

  //Compiling Vertex shader
  vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vscode, NULL);
  glCompileShader(vs);

  int result;
  glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
  if(!result){
    glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &result);

    char* infolog = (char*) malloc(result*sizeof(char));
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vs, result, &result, infolog);

    std::cout<<"Problem with vs compilation"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<infolog<<std::endl;

    free((void*)infolog);
    glDeleteShader(vs);
    vs = 0;
  }

  fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fscode, NULL);
  glCompileShader(fs);

  glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
  if(!result){
    glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &result);

    char* infolog = (char*) malloc(result*sizeof(char));
    glGetShaderInfoLog(fs, result, &result, infolog);

    std::cout<<"Problem with fs compilation"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<infolog<<std::endl;

    free((void*)infolog);
    glDeleteShader(fs);
    fs = 0;
  }

  glAttachShader(vs, program);
  int error;
  do{
    error = glGetError(); //error 1281
    std::cout<<error<<std::endl;
  } while(error != 0);
  glAttachShader(fs, program);

  glLinkProgram(program);
  glValidateProgram(program);

  glDetachShader(vs, program);
  glDetachShader(fs, program);
  glDeleteShader(vs);
  glDeleteShader(fs);
  free((void*)vscode);
  free((void*)fscode);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Error 1281 means INVALID_VALUE and is generated if either program or shader is not a value generated by OpenGL.

The first argument of [`glAttachShader`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glAttachShader.xhtml) is the program and the second argument is the shader:

<s>`glAttachShader(vs, program);`</s>

```cpp
glAttachShader(program, vs);
```